# な-adj/noun + ので [because structure]

Tags: grammar

Currently I am studying the ~ので,。。 grammar and, according to the book, I should use the short form before it, such as in `もっと勉強したので、頭が痛いです。`
Then, when I have a な-adj or noun, can I write it as follows for  the  presente  tense  ??:
`元気だので、外に行きます。`instead of `元気なので、外に行きます。`which is the correct form according to the text book? or is it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by the 'short form'. I'm guessing you mean the dictionary form rather than masu form. So, as you say, 勉強したので is correct.

元気**だ**ので is wrong. In the non-past tense nouns and na-adjectives both take な; never だ. So you would have 元気**な**ので, 先生**な**ので etc.

However, in the past tense you would still use だった; there is no replacement with な in this case. So 元気**だった**ので, 先生**だった**ので etc.